What is the best method to use when building GLM models to obtain AIC and AICc value in R?
I have built Poisson GLM models in several ways, and each method I used produced a different set of best models and different AIC values. This confused me. Below is a sample of my data.
Example<-structure(list(birds = c(9L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 2L), area = c(3.55, 2.52, 1.49, 1, 1.13, 1.49, 1.4, 0.57, 
1.11, 1.78, 1.63), density = c(2.5, 0.8, 1.3, 4, 0.9, 0.7, 2.9, 
1.8, 4.5, 2.8, 1.2), green = c(5.95, 5.62, 6.32, 6.04, 4.91, 
5.36, 7.15, 5.22, 6.8, 6.69, 6.47), open = c(3.69, 5, 3.94, 4.05, 
3.48, 3.97, 4.12, 4.29, 4.29, 3.56, 4), distance = c(0.6, 3, 
1, 0.9, 1, 1, 2.5, 3.2, 3.8, 2.5, 3), human = c(21.29, 22.76, 
23.02, 20.88, 21.26, 21.87, 23.19, 21.82, 19.49, 21.68, 19.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

fix(Example) # data table

I present the methods used to form models.
Method 1. Using a step method.
model.full = glm(birds ~ green + open + distance + human + offset(log(area)),
                 data=Example,
                 family = poisson(link="log"))
library(MASS)
simplifiedModel <- stepAIC(model.full,direction="both")

Data were generated for 4 models out of 15 possible models:
green, AIC=42,58;
green + human, AIC=43,53;
green + human + distance, AIC=44,23;
green + human + distance + open, AIC=46,17.
Method 2. Manual construction of models with all combinations of variables (15 models)
model.1=glm (birds ~ green + human + distance + open + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.final)
….
model.15=glm (birds ~ open + distance  + human + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.15)

Top 5 models:
green, AIC=42,58;
green + human, AIC=43,54;
green + open, AIC=43,98;
green + distance, AIC=44,03;
green + human + distance, AIC=44,23.
Method 3. Using comparison of models using the compareGLM function.
library(rcompanion)
compareGLM(model.1, model.2, model.3, model.4, model.5, model.6, model.7, model.8, model.9, model.10, model.11, model.12, model.13, model.14, model.15)

Top 5 models AIC:
green, AIC=44,58;
green + human, AIC=45,53;
green + open, AIC=45,98;
green + distance, AIC=45,98;
green + human + distance, AIC=46,23.
Top 5 models AICc:
green, AICc=48,01;
human, AICc=50,84;
open, AICc=51,45;
green + human, AICc=52,20;
green + open, AICc=52,65.
Which GLM model formation method is best to use to correctly determine AIC(AICc) when determining the best model?
